# Apply formatting to a column in a DataTable

Tags: c#, data-binding, datatable

I have a .NET DataTable with a column of type DateTime. I would like to format the date into Month, Year using the "y" format specifier.
I would prefer not having to iterate through all the rows/columns changing the value.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You're probably looking for a datagridview.

Comment: @laconicdev DateTime hasn't any format. You must apply format on its representation. How are you represent the date? In Console , in DateGridView etc?

Comment: I am binding the data table to a Telerik Grid view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataTable` just stores values. It does not provide formatting. Either format `DateTime` before putting it to `DataTable` (thus store it as a string), or do formatting on control, which your `DataTable` is bound to (e.g. `DataGridView` has `Format` property for cell style).